# Export JIRA Data

Tags: export, jira, jira-plugin

What is the best way to export all JIRA data (projects, issues, ...)? I saw that there is an API and a plugin mechanism which probably can provide all the information. But what is the easiest way to export the data? Does it work out of the box or do I have to implement a plugin?

Comment: What do you want to do with the exported data? Save it as a backup, create reports, ... ?

Comment: @user714965: I want to use a different issue tracker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, there are two main approaches to backup your JIRA data. The first one is to back up your database in which JIRA info is stored. The second one is to use the “Backup Data to XML feature”, which is a JIRA feature. Personally, I prefer the second one, because it can be restored to any database engine (MySQL, MSSQL, etc). In addition, as far as it is Xml, it can be compressed to a great extent.

Comment: And this backup feature obviously covers all the data, right? Looks like the way to go.. I'm just curious, why there are some plugins which export issues. Why is that needed if there is a XML backup feature?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Those domain specific exporter plug-ins are designed to export issues to different formats, e.g. Excel files, CVS files, Microsoft project files or even files that can be imported by other issue tracking systems.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a little [ruby utility](https://github.com/programmiersportgruppe/jira-sync) that uses JIRA's REST API to export all tickets for a given project to the local file system. It is available as a ruby gem, so the installation is trivial.

The tickets are saved as individual JSON files. The tool also supports incremental updates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using JIRA v1000.747.1 which has native export to CSV of issues.

If you navigate to https://[your-jira-instance]/issues you should see a query screen with results.  Fine tune that via the UI or go to the Advanced menu to do more complicated JQL.  Then you can click the export button (upper right) to export to XML/Word/HTML/CSV.

Answer (score 0):

The following add-ons will work out of the box, they are configurable and there is no need to code anything:

- [Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel) for XLSX output
- [PDF View Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.pdfview) for PDF output

You can use both **free for 30 days**, which should be sufficient to migrate your data to the new issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this web application to export the data to Word:

http://www.jiratoword.com/

It is quite basic and it could be improved but it is free.

Answer (score 0):

With no-code and free (MIT license), this [Jira data cycle time extractor](https://github.com/marian-kamenistak/jira-lead-cycle-time-duration-extractor) has helped me to extract data from JIRA and convert it into Excel or CSV format. It automates the inclusion of essential data and enhances it with flow status or stage start dates and durations with no further setting required. Consequently, it enables easy calculation and visualization of cycle time, lead time.

I recommend using it for my clients.

Comment: Promotion of a your own product/resource **without explicit disclosure that it's yours** may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behaviour is expected of users?](/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).