# Exporting a Cumlative Flow Diagram (CFD) from Jira

Tags: jquery, excel, jira, scrum

Objective:  Export Story state from Jira so I can display a CFD in Excel/other package. 
Problem:  Story history state (dates) do not appear to be 'exportable' into a CSV

I'm would like to export/create a Cumulative Flow Diagram (CFD) from Jira for Stories into a CSV/other. This is for story state.  However when executing the associated JQuery I cannot seem to gain access to an Issues history i.e. When the dates an Issue has passed from (To Do -> In Dev -> Ready for Test).  Displaying the CFD in JIRA is easy - however I do need to export for various reasons.  I have attempted using the Jql that to query the history via the status e.g.   status CHANGED FROM "In Progress" TO "Open" - but again date information does not appear to be made available.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export JIRA Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092559/export-jira-data)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. You _can_ export story information to CSV from the backlog view. If you want to export the actual Cumulative Flow Diagram, that will give you only the report image, not the underlying data

Answer (score 0):

The CFD JIRA Report (as of 2022) is displayed using the HTML `<canvas>` tag, so it is not a static image. It is also sized to the window, so the graph may not have the ratio of height to width you need.

There are two relatively easy ways to export the CFD. The first step for both is to resize your browser window so the CFG is the height/width ratio you want.

### Simple screen shot

This is the easiest way. Take a screen shot, ideally of just the parts of the diagram you want to capture. You can use a simple image editor (such as [The Gimp](https://gimp.org)) to trim the image, resize it, etc.

### Screenshot the surrounding `div`

The `ghx-chart-view` div here is what you want to screenshot. On Firefox, right-click the div in the inspector and choose "screenshot node".

[image: Cumulative Flow HTML code]